# use of coalesce to check for all variables being null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I use coalesce to check for all variables with different type precedence to all be NULL without encountering errors.

```
DECLARE 
@StartDate DATETIME = NULL,
@EndDate DATETIME = NULL,
@StateCode CHAR(2) = NULL,
@CountyCode CHAR(3) = NULL,
@ProducerName VARCHAR(64) = null,
@TaxID VARCHAR(9) = null,
@Farm INT = null

SELECT CASE WHEN COALESCE(
    @StartDate, 
    @EndDate, 
    @StateCode, 
    @CountyCode, 
    @ProducerName, 
    @TaxID, 
    @Farm) IS NULL 
THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END
```

Output: *'yes'*

adding `SELECT @StateCode = '22'` gives this error

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 94
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

this is valid

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 
   COALESCE(@StartDate, @EndDate) IS NULL 
   AND COALESCE(@StateCode, @CountyCode, @ProducerName, @TaxID) IS NULL 
   AND @farm IS NULL 
THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END
```

I'd love to know if there's another clever way to accomplish this in a terse manner so I don't have to remember to separate by type family.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As long as all the variables involved are of datatypes compatible with [`sql_variant`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173829.aspx) (they are in this case - basically no LOB datatypes, CLR types, or user defined datatypes) then you can use

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COALESCE(
    CAST(@StartDate as sql_variant), 
    @EndDate, 
    @StateCode, 
    @CountyCode, 
    @ProducerName, 
    @TaxID, 
    @Farm) IS NULL 
THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END
```

It is only necessary to cast one of the arguments as [`COALESCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190349.aspx)

> Returns the data type of expression with the highest data type
>   precedence.

And `sql_variant` has a very high datatype precedence (only beaten by user-defined data types and they would prevent the method from working anyway).

Personally I don't find this any more understandable then just finding the conjunction of the individual `IS NULL` results though.

Answer (score 10):

I find the simple syntax the more readable and less confusing. Why use functions (that can throw these weird errors) when you can check whether all variables (one by one) are `NULL`?:

```
CASE WHEN (@a IS NULL AND @b iS NULL .... AND @x iS NULL)
         THEN 'yes'
         ELSE 'no'
END
```

---

Alternative conditions - although less readable in my opinion would be:

```
CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS 
          ( SELECT @a, @b, @c, @d, @e
            EXCEPT
            SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
          ) 
         THEN 'yes'
         ELSE 'no'
END
```

and

```
CASE WHEN EXISTS 
          ( SELECT @a, @b, @c, @d, @e
            INTERSECT
            SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
          ) 
         THEN 'yes'
         ELSE 'no'
END
```

---

These last two options look similar to another (standard SQL but not yet implemented in SQL Server) option:

```
CASE WHEN (@a, @b, @c, @d, @e)
          IS NOT DISTINCT FROM
          (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) 
         THEN 'yes'
         ELSE 'no'
END
```

Answer (score 4):

COALESCE must return a valid datatype.

I think your problem is related to the way it works to determine datatype to return.

A quick workaround can be:

```
IF (@StartDate IS NULL AND @StateCode IS NULL AND ....)
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Yes'
END
ELSE
    SELECT 'No'
```